# Android return object as a activity result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to return object as a activity result from child activity to parent? Just something like:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(null);
resultIntent.putExtra("STRING_GOES_HERE", myObject);
setResult(resultIntent);
finish();
```

If it is possible, how should I retrieve `myObject` in parent activity?

I figured out, that to retrieve data I need to do something like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE_CHILD) {
        MyClass myObject = data.getExtra("STRING_GOES_HERE");
    }
}
```

Thing is that I get error, that can not resolve method 'getExtra'....

Comment: Read about Java serialisation.

Comment: Hmmm... The problem is that  `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` I can't pass object instead of integer at first...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot return an object, but you can return an intent containing your objects (provided they are primitive types, Serializable or Parcelable).

In your child activity, the code will be something like:

```
int resultCode = ...;
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("KEY_GOES_HERE", myObject);
setResult(resultCode, resultIntent);
finish();
```

In your parent activity you'll need to start the child activity with `startActivityForResult`:

```
public final static int REQ_CODE_CHILD = 1;

...
Intent child = new Intent(getPackageName(), "com.something.myapp.ChildActivity");
startActivityForResult(child, REQ_CODE_CHILD);
```

and then in the `onActivityResult`, you'll have:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE_CHILD) {
        MyClass myObject = (MyClass)data.getExtras().getSerializable("KEY_GOES_HERE");
    }

    ...
}
```

You can read about the methods on the [Activity javadoc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Sorry, didn't think straight.  You need to retrieve the bundle and then individual extra.  I updated my answer (based on assumption that your object is Serializable)

Comment: Your `MyClass` class needs to `implement Serializable` in order for this to work.

Comment: @Zapnologica did you read my previous comment? _based on assumption that your object is Serializable_

Comment: it was clear, object must be Serializable, additionally, for cross apps, add the serialVersionUID field to match object versions.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android), which explains how to use `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`.

This same process can be used for any object that is `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. Thus, if `myObject` is a custom class you've created, you will need to implement one of these interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setResult(int) read the [android activity reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) , specifically starting activities and getting results.